# req.param inside res.render causes strange console log

Tags: node.js, express

I am using using EJS templates with Node.js and Express. I am trying to pass a request parameter to my EJS template. It is working, however, for some reason my console log is reporting something strange.

**Versions:**

- Node 0.10.26
- Express 4.6.1
- EJS 0.8.5

**Here is the route that handles the ejs template:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var data = require('../data.json');
var pkg = require('../../package.json');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index',
    {
      'acs' : data.acs,
      'products' : data.products,
      'pkg' : pkg,
      'debug' : req.param('debug')
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is the console log** (I replaced anything long with "..." to save space)

```
var __stack = {
    lineno: 1,
    input: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\"> ... </html>\n",
    filename: "/web/app/views/index.ejs" };

function rethrow(err, str, filename, lineno){
  var lines = str.split('\n')
    , start = Math.max(lineno - 3, 0)
    , end = Math.min(lines.length, lineno + 3);

  // Error context
  var context = lines.slice(start, end).map(function(line, i){
    var curr = i + start + 1;
    return (curr == lineno ? ' >> ' : '    ')
      + curr
      + '| '
      + line;
  }).join('\n');

  // Alter exception message
  err.path = filename;
  err.message = (filename || 'ejs') + ':'
    + lineno + '\n'
    + context + '\n\n'
    + err.message;

  throw err;
}
try {
var buf = [];
with (locals || {}) { (function(){
 buf.push('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">...</html>\n'); })();
}
return buf.join('');
} catch (err) {
  rethrow(err, __stack.input, __stack.filename, __stack.lineno);
}
```

Like I said, it is working, however I can't tell why this is being logged in the console. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument passed to `res.render()` is passed to both the rendering engine **AND** your template. Because of this behavior, ejs (at least through 1.0 as of this writing), looks for a `debug` property in that object to [determine if debug information will be printed](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/218d9a91f34fa3f3368a07095a06efb56f1d7f83/lib/ejs.js#L233).